# Shortest way to coerce to array

Tags: tips, javascript

Given a variable a (non array) or (any[]) convert to (any[])

```
function example(s: string | string[]) {
   const e = Array.isArray(s) ? s: [s]
   return e
}
```

Is `Array.isArray(s) ? s: [s]` the shortest way?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I've added the [tag:tips] tag, since this is asking for a way to shorten some code in a specific language.

Comment: Do you know a concrete type if the value isn't an array?

Answer (score 19):

### 10 bytes

```
[s].flat()
```

This works by doing a shallow flat on `[s]`. So, if `s` is anything other than an array, nothing can be flattened and it will stay as `[s]`. But if `s` *is* an array, the outer `[]` will be flattened away, leaving a shallow clone of `s`.

Note that you can also use this to concat a number of arrays, either with other arrays or non-array elements:

```
[r,s,t].flat()
```

This is actually a trick I wasn't aware of until now. It's still a byte longer than `concat` though, if the first item's guaranteed to be an array:

```
r.concat(s,t)
```

When `r` could be anything, `[r,s,t].flat()` seems to be the best option.

Comment: In older versions you can still write `[].concat(r,s,t)`.

Answer (score 4):

aparently this works `t.map?t:[t]`

Comment: Works, but risky. `t` might be a different type of object with a `map` property. If you want to go down this route, `t.to?t:[t]` would also work in a modern browser